# How to dynamically create collections of derived objects?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, collections, derived-class

This question may appear to have been answered before but I have been unable to find exactly what I need. Here is my situation:

```
// Base class
interface IAnimal {};
public abstract class Animal : IAnimal{}

// Derived classes
interface IDog {}
public class Dog : Animal, IDog { }
interface ICat { }
public class Cat : Animal, ICat { }
interface ITiger { }
public class Tiger : Animal, ITiger { }
interface ILion { }
public class Lion : Animal, ILion { }

// Collection Classes
interface IPets { }
public class Pets
{
    IDog dog = new Dog();
    ICat cat = new Cat();
}
interface ICircus { }
public class Circus
{
    ITiger tiger = new Tiger();
    ILion lion = new Lion();
}
```

I would like to create the collections at run time in an generic Event class by reading in a list animals from xml that would make up the collection. What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an answer to my own question. Maybe this will help others.

I chose a very generic example to illustrate my situation because I have uses for this in many places in Windows Forms, XNA and Silverlight that are all very different.

When I used the Activator, I found out that it assumes the executing assembly. My method is in a library so I had to load a different assembly. Next I had to make sure that I had the right namespace. My base class is in a library and the derived classes are in another namespace so this will require refactoring to properly create the list.

Another problem I found was that the Activator assumes a constructor with no parameters. In my test case all my derived classes are XNA game components with a parameter of type Game.

Have to do some refactoring to test out the interfaces and how the game objects are to interact.

Will be back to this list when I have something further.

Comment: The constructors I'm invoking using Activator.CreateInstance take a parameter of type `XElement` actually.

Answer (score 0):

Does this sort of example help? (It's from some of my code I happened to have handy.) The key point here is the use of reflection in `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`.

```
public static List<dynamic> LoadChildEntities(XElement entityElt)
{
    var children = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach(XElement childElt in entityElt.Elements("entity"))
    {
        // Look up the C# type of the child entity.
        string childTypename = "MyNamespace." + Convert.ToString(childElt.Attribute("type").Value);
        Type childType = Type.GetType(childTypename);

        if(childType != null)
        {
            // Construct the child entity and add it to the list.
            children.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(childType, childElt));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No such class: " + childTypename);
        }
    }

    return children;
}
```

If you want a list of `IAnimal` instead, it wouldn't be too tricky to change.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: I didn't realize that the comment was sent when I hit return. It will take me a bit of time to apply your answer. Bear with me.

Comment: This turns out to be a whole lot more complicated. Was able to create the list with some challenges that will necessitate me refactoring my classes.